# MaskedEditText hint is not showing properly in android

Tags: android

Am using MaskedEditText is a simple Android EditText with customizable input mask support.I have a field called IP address.For that i have to set it like "000.000.000" format.While typing its setting correctly.But the hint is showing in different way.Am using this gradle,

> compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'

My xml code is like,

```
        <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
        android:id="@+id/rp_ipET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:hint="000.000.000"
        mask:mask="###.###.###"
        mask:keep_hint="true"
        />
```

And in my activity ,

```
    rp_ipET=(MaskedEditText)view.findViewById(R.id.rp_ipET);
    rp_ipET.setCharRepresentation('#');
    rp_ipET.setMask("###.###.###");
```

Please find the attached screenshot,
[image: MaskedEditTextHint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this

```
  mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:hint="000.000.000"
    mask:mask="###.###.###"
```

by

```
mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
android:padding="6dp"
mask:mask="###.###.###"
android:hint="000000000"
```

Comment: Perfect..Thank you so much.